# cannot convert from list<object> to list<callable<type>> java

Tags: java

I have the following code where I'm trying to permit threads in my project.And here's my method which executes one step for each existing PrgState (namely each thread).

```
public void oneStepForAllPrg(List<PrgState> prgList){

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    prgList.forEach(prg ->controllerMethod(false,prg.toString()));
    //here prepare the list of callables
    List<Callable<PrgState>> callList = new ArrayList<>();
    callList = prgList.stream()
            .map(p ->(() -> {return p.oneStep();}))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); //receive error here
    //start the execution of the callables
    //it returns the list of new created threads

    List<PrgState> newPrgList =        //the error here if I modify
             executor.invokeAll(callList).stream()
                         .map(future -> {try  {
                                  return future.get();
                         }catch (Exception e){
                              System.out.println("Error ctrl method oneStepForAllPrg");
                         }
                         })
         .filter(p -> p!=null )
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
    prgList.addAll(newPrgList);
    prgList.forEach(prg ->prg.toString());

public void controllerMethod(boolean flag,String s){
    PrgState prg;
    if (flag == false){
        writeToFile(s);
    }
    if (flag == true){
        //
    }
}
```

How to manage the error:

```
cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Callable<PrgState>>?
```

I mean, the both of them are lists, why is not permitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming PrgState.oneStep() returns a PrgState, try changing

```
.map(p ->(() -> {return p.oneStep();}))
```

to

```
.map(p -> ((Callable<PrgState>)(() -> p.oneStep())))
```

You can't just sprinkle lambdas around, they're only syntactic sugar for an anonymous class, the compiler needs to know what type of class it is

EDIT:

Second error has nothing to do with the first; your future -> lambda doesn't return anything if there's an exception, that can't possibly compile.

EDIT2:

This code will generate your newPrgList:

```
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.*;

...

Executor e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (100);
List<PrgState> = prgList.stream ()
                        .map (p -> supplyAsync ( () -> p.oneStep (), e))
                        .reduce (new ArrayList<PrgState> (), (a, f) -> {
  try {
    a.add (f.get ());
    return a;
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    throw new RuntimeException (e1);
  }
}, (a1, a2) -> {
  ArrayList<PrgState> a = new ArrayList<> ();
  a.addAll (a1);
  a.addAll (a2);
  return a;
});
```

Comment: Your idea is great, thank you but if I modify there in another place I get another error: Cannot convert from list<Object> to list<PrgState> .I edited where it gives me the error.

Comment: I've done like you said it and there it is the error.

Answer (score 0):

This will might help you.

Define the chunk size to something lets say 10000.

```
int chunkSize = 10000;
final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);     
List<CallableObj> recordsList = dataList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / chunkSize)).values()
.stream().map(obj -> new CallableObj(obj)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the Callable object is like this:

```
    public class CallableObj<T> implements Callable<T> {
        private List<Object> recordsList;


        public CallableObj(List<Object> recordsList) {
            super();
            this.recordsList = recordsList;
        }

        @Override
        public T call() throws Exception{
             //code....
        }
    }
```

Hope this solves the purpose.

Thanks,

Atul